# Making my android app become faster

Tags: android, onclick, start-activity

I'm currently making my second android app using android studio.
And for some reason I feel that each time an OnClick method is called which is swiching between intent there's a delay of about half a second before it starts proccessing.
This fact makes my app not that smoothly.

An example:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.mButton:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,devPage.class));
                break;
    }
```

So, I wanted to ask whether if this is the common way to swich layout?
And if there's is a different click event which has shorter response time?
And if you have any tips for making app perfomance better I would like to hear.
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the click event - it's what you're doing in the `onCreate` and `onResume` of the activity you're switching to

Answer (score 0):

First - What kind of device are you using, if you're using the emulator, you need to consider that this is not the actual device and it can run much faster in one,

Second - try to declare the intent before

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

`Intent intentShipmentOut = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClassName.class);`
`startActivity(intentShipmentOut);`

`}`

Answer (score 0):

I used the Android Monitor and saw that my app was using much allocation memory to make it flow slower than I wanted.
In addition my code was complexed, and I managed to make it simple with the same result.
I am not sure if its true but each time I'm switching intents I also call finish() method to free the unneeded activities.